# matlab: append a character in a martix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix, say 
A= zeros(5,5,5,5);
and assigned a decimal value for each cell

Now I want to add a character 'x' for every cell
How should I do it?

I have tried to convert A to cell matrix using num2cell
but when I add the 'x' to it, I got the out of range warning and my value disappeared, leaving a single 'x' in every cell

```
A=zeros(5,5,5,5)
%some calculation for some decimal value
for %something
    assign value to every cell
end
A=num2cell(A)
A=concat(A,'x')
```

Comment: Show us how you did that

Comment: I have paste my code. As assigning value is quite a long code, so I just put some comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to transform `3` to `3x`, you cannot store it in a number format any longer, but you have to transform it to string. However, once it is a string, it's very easy to add a letter:

```
A = zeros(5,5,5,5);
%// fill A with numbers

%// convert to cell
C = num2cell(A);

%// transform all numbers in C to strings using num2str
%//     and add the letter 'x' by catenation
%// cellfun applies the function to each element of the cell array
C = cellfun(@(x)[num2str(x),'x'], C, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Note that as @Daniel correctly states, you can skip a step in the process and run `arrayfun(@(x)[num2str(x),'x'], A, 'UniformOutput', false);` on the numeric array directly - the `'UniformOutput',false` statement means that `arrayfun` will return the results in a cell array.

Comment: `num2cell` is not necessary, use `C = arrayfun(@(x)[num2str(x),'x'], A, 'UniformOutput', false);`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

similarly:

```
B = cell(5,5,5,5);
D = cellfun(@(c) [c '0'],B,'UniformOutput',0);
E = cellfun(@(c) [c 'x'],D,'UniformOutput',0);
```